# How can I delete all rows within a table in a mysql database, which value = 0 for one of the columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

So basically, it's like this:

The table is called `phpbb_posts`

The column name is `post_approved`

I want to run a query which deletes all rows in `phpbb_posts` table in which the `post_approved` value is 0 (All rows contain either a 1 or a 0 value for the column `post_approved`)

I wanted to make sure I am running the correct query, before running it.

```
DELETE FROM phpbb_posts
WHERE EXISTS(
              SELECT * 
              FROM phpbb_posts
              WHERE (post_approved = 0) 
            )
```

Please tell me if this code is correct; or if it is wrong, please tell me the correct code.

---

---

CODE FIXED (thanks!):

```
DELETE FROM phpbb_posts WHERE post_approved = 0
```

**RESULT:**

```
35743 rows deleted. ( Query took 1.3562 sec )
```

> *P.S. FOR THOSE WONDERING, THIS REMOVES ALL SPAM POSTS FROM PHPBB IN
> ONE FELL SWOOP! (assuming you don't have any valid posts you want to
> approve). Instead of going through moderator and "disapproving" for
> 50,000 pages, you can do this! :) :)
> and yes I checked in the moderator queue and all the spam posts i never approved are gone! YAY!*

Comment: Delete from phpbb_posts where post_approved = 0.  The subquery is not needed

Answer (score 4):

just do

```
    DELETE FROM phpbb_posts WHERE post_approved = 0
```

Comment: Will this delete the WHOLE ROWS which contain `post_approved` = 0 ?

Comment: I will accept as best as soon as I am allowed. And I will upvote when I have enough points.

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
DELETE FROM phpbb_posts
WHERE post_approved = 0
```

that should do it fine.

Comment: Don't I need the select statement for safety?

Answer (score 2):

I would think just:

```
DELETE FROM phpbb_posts
WHERE post_approved = 0;
```

Would suffice

Comment: Will this delete the WHOLE ROWS which contain `post_approved` = 0 ?

Comment: It will delete all rows from the table where post_approved is 0

Comment: all the rows where the column 'post_approved' for that row has a value of 0.  are you trying to get something else, only delete first record or something unusual.  i ouwld add more to the question if you are.